# Get RHEL version from uname -r | sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am writing a script that should only be run on RHEL6 or RHEL7 hosts.
I figured it would be easy.  Use `uname -r`, `sed` and a clever regex.
Well I can't come up with a the clever regex :( ...

Here are the details of what I am trying to do:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed -e's/... clever stuff here .../\1/g'
7
```

Here's what I have tried, please don't laugh:

```
$ uname -r | sed -e's/^.*\.el\(\d)\.*$/\1/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: Unmatched ( or \(
$ uname -r | sed -e's/^.*\.el\{1}(\d)\.*$/\1/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: Unmatched \{
$ uname -r | sed -e's/^.*\.el{1}\(\d\)\.*$/\1/g'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed -e's/^.*\.el\(\d\)\.*$/\1/g'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed -e's/^.*\.el\(\.\)\.*$/\1/g'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
3.10
$ uname -r | sed 's/el+\.[0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: Unmatched ) or \)
$ uname -r | sed 's/el+\.\([0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed 's/el+\.\([0-9]\)\..*/\1/'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed 's/^.*\.el+\.\([0-9]\)\..*/\1/'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: do you want `cat /etc/redhat-release`?

Comment: That will probably work for most people, but sometimes the sysadmins where I work do screwy things to the `/etc/redhat-release` file so I don't trust it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing the kernel version to figure out the RHEL Version is a terrible idea, because what if a kernel is released that doesn't follow the same naming scheme?  While it might work for now, it's a fragile solution.

There are several ways of determining the current RHEL version.

The easiest, as glenn jackman suggested in his comment, may be to parse `/etc/redhat-release`, which looks like (for RHEL 7):

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

And for RHEL 6:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

A slightly better method is to query the version of the installed `redhat-release` package:

```
$ rpm -q --qf '%{VERSION}\n' -f /etc/redhat-release
7.2
```

This says "tell me the version of the package that owns `/etc/redhat-release`".  The above example was run under RHEL7; the same thing when run under RHEL6 yieilds:

```
$ rpm -q --qf '%{VERSION}\n' -f /etc/redhat-release
6Server
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have several options.

```
uname -r | sed 's/^.*\.el\([0-9]*\)\..*$/\1/'
```

should do the trick.

That says "look for a period followed by 'el' followed by some number of digits followed by a period.  Replace the whole line with just those digits."

Let's go over your attempts.  Mostly you need to understand the difference between different flavors of regular expression syntax; sed is not Perl.

```
$ uname -r | sed -e 's/^.*\.el\(\d)\.*$/\1/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: Unmatched ( or \(
$ uname -r | sed -e 's/^.*\.el\{1}(\d)\.*$/\1/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: Unmatched \{
```

In both of these, you used a backslashed opening bracket but tried to close it without the backslash.  In sed, `\(` is closed by `\)` and `\{` by `\}`.

```
$ uname -r | sed -e 's/^.*\.el{1}\(\d\)\.*$/\1/g'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
```

`{1}` is literal - so you're looking for a literal digit 1 inside literal curly braces.  Since it didn't find any such thing, it didn't make any changes and the line comes out unchanged.

```
$ uname -r | sed -e 's/^.*\.el\(\d\)\.*$/\1/g'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
```

This would almost work if `sed` understood `\d` by default.  But the fact that you have `\.*` is what messes it up - it only matches 0 or more periods.  You want `\..*` - a literal period followed by any number of characters.  Also, sed *doesn't* understand `\d` by default. You need `[0-9]` there.

```
$ uname -r | sed -e 's/^.*\.el\(\.\)\.*$/\1/g'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
```

That backslash in front of the dot inside the parentheses means you are looking for a literal period instead of any character.  And you have the `\.*` again.

```
$ uname -r | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
3.10
```

That did exactly what you asked it to.. what were you looking for here?

```
$ uname -r | sed 's/el+\.[0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: Unmatched ) or \)
```

You have the `\)` but no `\(`.

```
$ uname -r | sed 's/el+\.\([0-9]\+\)\..*/\1/'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed 's/el+\.\([0-9]\)\..*/\1/'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
$ uname -r | sed 's/^.*\.el+\.\([0-9]\)\..*/\1/'
3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
```

`+` matches a literal plus sign.

Comment: or perhaps `uname -r | grep -oP '(?<=\.el)\d+'`

Comment: Good explanation. You can do that too: `sed 's/.*\.el//;s/\..*//'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ uname -r | sed 's/.*el\([0-9]\).*/\1/g'
```

or

```
$ uname -r | sed -r 's/.*el([0-9]).*/\1/g'
```